# How to refresh IdToken from AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I've set up a Lambda trigger for an SQS queue, so that the Lambda function is called when the queue gets any new messages.

The Lambda function (in Python) is being used to call an API endpoint, which requires a AWS Cognito IdToken, like this:

```
api_endpoint = 'https://api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/xyz'
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer id_token_here"}
```

However after 24 hours, the `IdToken` gets expired and I've generate a new one using Cognito `admin-initiate-auth`.

How can I manage this in Lambda? I can't add the `admin-initiate-auth` command in the lambda function because then it'll run it for each message, which I believe isn't ideal.

What is the best way to handle this? Is there a way in which the `IdToken` keeps getting refreshed whenever it's expired or about to expire, without failing the API request (due to expired token)?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply *refreshSession* with [InitiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html) API Call with REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH.

Once you get the token you store it in [AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/tutorials_basic.html) and then fetch it from there on each lambda invocation. If the token you fetched from secrets manager is not valid anymore you simply refresh and update secrets manager's value as well.

Below is some sample code

```
    def initiate_auth(client, username, password):
    ...

        resp = client.admin_initiate_auth(
                    UserPoolId=USER_POOL_ID,
                    ClientId=CLIENT_ID,
                    AuthFlow='ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
                    AuthParameters={
                        'USERNAME': username,
                        'SECRET_HASH': secret_hash,
                        'PASSWORD': password,
                    },
                    ClientMetadata={
                    'username': username,
                    'password': password,
                })

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
    ...
    resp, msg = initiate_auth(client, username, password)
    ...
    if resp.get("AuthenticationResult"):
        return {'message': "success", 
                "error": False, 
                "success": True, 
                "data": {
                "id_token": resp["AuthenticationResult"]["IdToken"],
        "refresh_token": resp["AuthenticationResult"]["RefreshToken"],
        "access_token": resp["AuthenticationResult"]["AccessToken"],
        "expires_in": resp["AuthenticationResult"]["ExpiresIn"]
        "token_type": resp["AuthenticationResult"]["TokenType"]
                }}
        else:
        ....
```

Comment: So you mean I should check for the authentication validity in each Lambda function invocation, and if if the token expires, I should refresh it, right?

Comment: yes, you dont have to go through the whole process for regenerating the token, you can ask for refreshing the token provided you have the  time window where even your refresh token is valid. Plus every time you get a new token, try to store it somewhere like [AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/tutorials_basic.html) and on every lambda invocation, you fetch the token from there and check for validity if expired then refresh.